# Render animation with compositing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, glare

Hello everyone I'm trying to render a sequence of images with compositing. I add an Image node, specify a link to the already rendered sequence in it, add a Glare node to create Fog Glow. Glow works in the preview window, but when I render the animation, Glow disappears in the final picture. Why can this happen?

[image]

Comment: you forgot to plug the Glare node to the *Composite* node as well. plugging it into *Viewer* node only let's preview the output. plug it into Composite node as well.

Comment: It works. Thanx!